Convert values of data class
Assuming I have a data class like this
data class PersonDTO(
    val id: Long?,
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
)

which I then persist in the database on this entity
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
class Person(
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = true)
    var firstName: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = true)
    var lastName: String? = null,
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = 0
}

like so
personRepository.save(
    Person(
        firstName = personDto.firstName,
        lastName = personDto.lastName
    )
)

Since firstName and lastName are nullable, I want the data class PersonDTO to behave the following way: If firstName is of length === 0, return null for firstName (and the same for lastName).
Is there a way to achieve this?

So you just want to do personDto.firstName.takeUnless { it.isEmpty() }?

@Sweeper I want the PersonDTO data class to return null if the string is empty. If not, return the string. I do not want to write that everywhere I use the DTO, but implement it once in the data class itself. Ideally, I won't have to make the fields in the data class nullable.

How about adding new properties like nonEmptyFirstName and nonEmptyLastName to the data class?

You don't want the properties to be nullable, but you also want them to return null sometimes. Do you realise how contradictory that is?

I would just add new properties to the data class:
data class PersonDTO(
    val id: Long?,
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
) {
    val nonEmptyFirstName: String?
        get() = firstName.takeUnless { it.isEmpty() }
    val nonEmptyLastName: String?
        get() = lastName.takeUnless { it.isEmpty() }
}

personRepository.save(
    Person(
        firstName = personDto.nonEmptyFirstName,
        lastName = personDto.nonEmptyLastName
    )
)

Or write a function to convert to a Person directly.
fun PersonDTO.toPerson() = Person(
    firstName = firstName.takeUnless { it.isEmpty() },
    lastName = lastName.takeUnless { it.isEmpty() }
)


If this doesn't have to be a data class, you can achieve this without using any extra properties. The properties firstName and lastName are nullable, but the constructor does not accept null.
class PersonDTO(
    val id: Long?,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
) {
    val firstName: String? = firstName
        get() = field?.takeUnless { it.isEmpty() }
    val lastName: String? = lastName
        get() = field?.takeUnless { it.isEmpty() }
}


I would prefer to name the properties firstNameOrNull to keep to existing naming conventions (consistent with xxxOrNull in the stdlib). To me, nonEmptyFirstName suggests it would throw if it's empty.

@k314159 The convention used in stdlib is that the variant without OrNull throws, but firstName never throws. To me this doesn't seem like this OrNull suffix pattern fits. How about nonEmptyFirstNameOrNull perhaps?

I see what you mean. I think nonEmptyFirstNameOrNull is too long.

From my perspective, you can achieve that in the following manner
First Change
data class PersonDTO(
    val id: Long?,
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
) {
    // Use Function based calls
    fun getFirstName(): String? {
        return firstName.ifEmpty { null }
    }

    fun getLastName(): String? {
        return lastName.ifEmpty { null }
    }

    // Use calling variables directly
    val nullableFirstName: String? = firstName.ifEmpty { null }
    val nullableLastName: String? = lastName.ifEmpty { null }
}

Second Change
personRepository.save(
    Person(
        firstName = personDto.getFirstName(),
        lastName = personDto.getLastName()
    )
)

